# JOIN tables inside a subquery in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400

I'm having trouble with paginating with joined tables in DB2. I want to return rows 10-30 of a query that contains an INNER JOIN.

This works:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY U4SLSMN.SLNAME) AS ID,
        U4SLSMN.SLNO, U4SLSMN.SLNAME, U4SLSMN.SLLC
    FROM U4SLSMN) AS P
WHERE P.ID BETWEEN 10 AND 30
```

This does not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY U4SLSMN.SLNAME) AS ID,
        U4SLSMN.SLNO, U4SLSMN.SLNAME, U4SLSMN.SLLC, U4CONST.C4NAME
    FROM U4SLSMN INNER JOIN U4CONST ON U4SLSMN.SLNO = U4CONST.C4NAME
) AS P
WHERE P.ID BETWEEN 10 AND 30
```

The error I get is:

> Selection error involving field *N.

Note that the JOIN query works correctly by itself, just not when it's run as a subquery.

How do I perform a join inside a subquery in DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me on v7.1 TR9

Here's what I actually ran:

```
select * 
from ( select rownumber() over (order by vvname) as ID, idescr, vvname
       from olsdta.ioritemmst 
            inner join olsdta.vorvendmst on ivndno = vvndno
     ) as P
where p.id between 10 and 30;
```

I much prefer the CTE version however:

```
with p as 
 ( select rownumber() over (order by vvname) as ID, idescr, vvname
     from olsdta.ioritemmst 
          inner join olsdta.vorvendmst on ivndno = vvndno
 ) 
select *
from p
where p.id between 10 and 30;
```

Finally, note that at 7.1 TR11 (7.2 TR3), IBM added support of the LIMIT and     OFFSET clauses.  Your query could be re-done as follows:

```
SELECT 
      U4SLSMN.SLNO, U4SLSMN.SLNAME, U4SLSMN.SLLC, U4CONST.C4NAME
 FROM U4SLSMN INNER JOIN U4CONST ON U4SLSMN.SLNO = U4CONST.C4NAME 
ORDER BY U4SLSMN.SLNAME
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 9;
```

However, note that the LIMIT & OFFSET clauses are only supported in prepared or embedded SQL.  You can't use them in STRSQL or STRQMQRY.  I believe the "Run SQL Scripts" GUI interface does support them.   Here's an [article about LIMIT & OFFSET](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg011216-story03.html)